# Selecting a cell in an HTML table by sibling cell value and column header

Tags: html, xpath, html-table

I've got an HTML table of which I cannot depend on how many rows and/or columns it will contain - so using index numbers is not possible.  Here is an example of the table:

```
|Name|Description|Credit|Balance|
|Bob |    Rent   |400.00|1000.00|
|Jim |    Car    |100.00|4000.00|
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Credit</th>
       <th>Balance</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Bob</td>
       <td>Rent</td>
       <td>400.00</td>
       <td>1000.00</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Jim</td>
       <td>Car</td>
       <td>100.00</td>
       <td>4000.00</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to get the credit amount for which ever name I need.

Comment: How do you know which column is the credit amount?  Will it always have a `<th>` of "Credit"?  Will it always be the third column?, same question for the name

Comment: Why not just calculate the amount from the datasource used to create this table? I suppose you don't create the data manually.

Comment: The th's in your tbody should probably be td's.  I'm also not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  Maybe an example would help?

Comment: @DMoses, I know which column because of the header "Credit" and I know which row because I'm looking for the credit for a particular person.

Comment: @Samuel, lol good call - fixed.  This was just a sample table I made for this question.  Basically I wanted to select a cell by column header and row - the criteria for row selection is more ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
//tr[td[.="Jim"]]/td[count(ancestor::table/thead/tr/th[.="Credit"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

Comment: Nice.  I think this will match "Jim" in any column though?  Might be a problem if Jim were to appear in the Description column.

Comment: You're right, this table is only a sample table though - fortunately I won't have to worry about this in the actual table as the column I'm using to select the row is unique.